# Programmatically add roles after authentication

Tags: java, jsf, authentication, glassfish-3

I have the following JSF 2.1 login form, running in Glassfish 3.1

```
<h:form id="loginForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5">
            <h:outputText value="Username" />
            <h:inputText value="#{loginHandler.username}" />
            <h:outputText value="Password:" />
            <h:inputText value="#{loginHandler.password}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="" />
            <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginHandler.login}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

And the following backing bean.

```
public String login() throws IOException, LoginException {

    log.debug("Trying to login with username " + username);

    HttpSession session = getRequest().getSession(true);

    try {
        getRequest().login(username, password);

        // if OK, add Roles
                    ????????
                    ...................

    } catch (ServletException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    log.debug("USER principal === " + getRequest().getUserPrincipal());

    return "home";
}
```

The question is, how can I add roles programmatically to the UserPrincipal after successful login?

Update 1: I tried to get the Subject by using the following code but subject == null.

```
Subject thisSubject = Subject.getSubject(AccessController
                .getContext());
```

Thanks,
Coen

Comment: do you want to hardcode roles for every user? If you use container authentification the roles should come from that authentification realm.

Comment: Hi, I need to query another LDAP tree for certain roles and assign these roles to the user. The roles are defined in the web.xml. So authentication is container managed, but assigning the roles is not.

Answer (score 5):

I came up with the following solution to add roles programmatically after login, which works at least on GlassFish 3.1.2 build 23.

```
import com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityContext;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.web.integration.PrincipalGroupFactory;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import org.glassfish.security.common.Group;

public class GlassFishUtils {
    public static void addGroupToCurrentUser(String groupName, String realmName) {
        Subject subject = SecurityContext.getCurrent().getSubject();
        Set<Principal> principals = subject.getPrincipals();
        Group group = PrincipalGroupFactory.getGroupInstance(groupName, realmName);
        if (!principals.contains(group))
            principals.add(group);
    }
}
```

You will need to add `security.jar` and `common-util.jar` from GlassFish to your project libraries.

And don't forget to create a `<security-role>` section in your web.xml for the roles you wish to add.

Note that I am using functionality which does not appear to be part of a published stable API, so there is no guarantee that this will keep working in future releases of GlassFish.

I got the information on how to add roles from the source code of `sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule.commit()` of GlassFish.
If a future GlassFish release breaks my code, this function would be a good place to start in order to find out how to fix it.

Comment: What does "realname" refer to? The login name that becomes the principal? As in if in JSF you do a: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal(); Yeah? No?

Comment: It's not "real", but "realm", as in the JAAS authentication realm. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbxj/index.html for more information on realms. The realmName parameter is the string identifying the realm, as configured in GlassFish.

Comment: &lt;BIG grin&gt. I need new glasses then. lol. Yeah I know the realM name. I have already customized JDBC realm to do more of what I needed to do and to get around the dumb way they expect the table s to be set up (as well as allowing for dealing with salted passwords etc. :) Thanks for the answer. This looks worth a try at least. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, now with GF4 the security.jar does not hold `com.sun.enterprise.security.web.integration.PrincipalGroupFactory` anymore. Any clue where it is now?

Answer (score 3):

OK, i have figured out a workaround, which is not 100% correct in my point of view but suggestions are welcome :)

```
public void login() throws IOException, LoginException {

    log.debug("Trying to login with username " + username);

    try {
        getRequest().login(username, password);

        HttpSession session = getRequest().getSession(true);
        Subject subject = (Subject) session
                .getAttribute("javax.security.auth.subject");

        if (subject == null) {

            log.debug("Subject is null, creating new one");

            subject = new Subject();
            subject.getPrincipals().add(new PlainRolePrincipal("USER"));
            subject.getPrincipals().add(new PlainRolePrincipal("ADMIN"));

        }

        log.debug("HAS USER " + getRequest().isUserInRole("USER"));
        log.debug("HAS ADMIN " + getRequest().isUserInRole("ADMIN"));
        log.debug("HAS REPORT " + getRequest().isUserInRole("REPORT"));

        session.setAttribute("javax.security.auth.subject", subject);

        log.debug("USER principal === " + getRequest().getUserPrincipal());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .redirect("pages/home.jsf");

    } catch (ServletException e) {

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Login",
                new FacesMessage("Invalid Username/Password combination"));

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Also I use the following info bean to retrieve the subject and check the principals.

```
 @ManagedBean(name = "userInfo")
 @SessionScoped
 public class UserInformation {

/**
 * Fetches current logged in username.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public String getUsername() {

    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getRemoteUser();

}



public boolean isUserInRole(String roleName) {
    Subject subject = (Subject) getRequest().getSession().getAttribute(
            "javax.security.auth.subject");

    for (Principal p : subject.getPrincipals()) {
        if (p.getName().equals(roleName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}


public static HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    Object request = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getRequest();
    return request instanceof HttpServletRequest ? (HttpServletRequest) request
            : null;
}
```

}

So I workaround the isUserInRole mechanism, the real isUserInRole method returns only true on USER, because that role is set when authenticating.

From the JSF pages I can now do

```
<p:menuitem value="Create" action="#{menuController.XXXXXCreate}"
                ajax="false" helpText="Create new XXXXX"
                disabled="#{!userInfo.isUserInRole('ADMIN')}" />
```

Hope this helps other users, any improvement suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Where did you find the attribute: "javax.security.auth.subject" ? Is this a published attribute that is not likely to change. I am curious to use this as well.

And what do you mean by: "So I workaround the isUserInRole mechanism, "?